# How do I use JSON for relational type data - best to just repeat data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, json

I would like to create JSON to act as a small database of cars.  If I were to use MySQL, I would create a Maker table so as not to repeat the makers and maker attributes for every single car.  What is the best way to do this in JSON?  for instance, if I have the following attributes for maker:

"Name": "Ford",
"URL": "ford.com",
"Founded" : "some year"
etc...

and then the car list
"Name": "Mustang",
"first year" : "some year",
"maker" : "Ford"
"maker URL" :"ford.com"

I don't want to repeat the maker attributes for every ford car.  Should I have two JSON files and link them together by a maker id or unique maker name?  or should I just allow the maker attributes to repeat for every ford car?  I'm specifically doing this in Objective-C/iOS so I can use the data on an iPhone.  I will pull the JSON in to an Array for parsing and viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use core data which is SQLLite and create the same tables you would use in mySQL ? 
If you really want to stick with JSON, then the "right" anser depends on what is important to 
you. e.g saving space ? ease of update (what if the Ford URL changes to cars.ford) ? fewer read accesses ? etc

Comment: I will need to update the data via web services maybe once per month and felt like core data was a bit of overkill for my data.  I want the app to have ease of update and fast performance