# How to best use Solr for relational records?

Tags: solr, sunspot, relation

Given the following relational data scheme -

- Posts can have 0 to many tags
- Tags have 0 to many aliases

In Sunspot / Solr, would be the best practice to search for posts by tag (or a tag alias)?

Comment: For reference, this question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143094/how-do-i-use-json-for-relational-type-data-best-to-just-repeat-data

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to index posts with an array of the full text of all associated tags and their aliases. This will work but seems wasteful in terms of storage resources and possibly not optimally performant.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above answer, you can use the [synonyms feature](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) to store aliases. 
The synonyms does not have to be static. The latest versions of solr have made it very simple to [programmatically manage synonyms](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managed+Resources).